# How can I scale a 0-5v signal down to both a 0.5-4.5v signal and a 0.5-2.0 signal simultaneously?

Tags: voltage, power, signal

I need to split a 0-5v signal into a 0.5v-4.5v signal and a 0.5-2.0v signal. How can I achieve this?

I can achieve this with a single board computer -- but that seems inelegant and overkill.

Comment: seems you could use a couple of resistive dividers to do that,

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/357402/supply-voltages-for-inverting-amplifier/357409#357409 for tips on this. You would need two such circuits.

Comment: Linearly or don't care?

Comment: what load impedance are they driving? Resistive voltage dividers would be the simplest and most elegant way of doing this, but their design depends on knowing the load.

Comment: @Jasen  I don't see how a resistor network is going to turn, for example, a 0.1 volt signal into something greater than 0.5 volts.  You can convert 0-to-5 to 0-to-4.5, that's just a span change, but you're not going to get a 0.5 offset with resistors.

Comment: @Andyaka I want linear, but i'm trying to learn how to do it **at all**

Comment: @Neil_UK I'm trying to replicate the output of two automotive hall effect sensors; the impedance is not listed in the part spec and I don't yet have a part to test in hand. I have a suspicion that it's in the 0-4ohm range, but i'm mostly just trying to learn the basic ways I could scale this voltage once I learn more about what i'm working with. Basic/general advice is appreciated!

Comment: @user248244 Are you absolutely certain that it is in the 0-4 Ω range? Do you understand Neil_UK's question?

Comment: @Neil_UK  forgot to mention; I think the hall output is something like 150mA if it's anything like similar sensors in the system; but without a part in hand I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: @HarrySvensson No, i'm not absolutely sure -- no part in hand. I only partially understand the question, so I covered as much about it as I can infer : the output of the sensor I am trying to replicate **may** be something around 150mA, the expected resistance of the sensor **may** be something around 0-4ohm. Any clarification that could help me provide better information would be appreciated.

Comment: @Harry  I don't get it.  How is he going to get 0.5 volts out of any resistor network when he puts in 0.0?  He should be getting 0.5 out with 0.0 in, and 4.5 out with 5.0 in (that's the easy part).  Could you give some sort of link or something besides "Y connection", please?

Comment: Guys, I was trying to tell @Jasen and Harry nicely that you can not accomplish the OP's problem with any kind or number of resistor network(s).  It is simply impossible, with just resistors, to put 0.0 volts in and get 0.5 volts (i.e., the offset) out.  You would have to have some active components / external power supply to get the offset.

Comment: @MichaelGorsich, resistors and a voltage supply makes it possible. and if you're not allowed voltage nothing is possible.

Comment: @Jasen So you agree with me then, right?  My original comment was that the OP's requirements can't be met with resistors alone, which was correct.  Not sure why you added the "...and if you're not allowed.." part.  You do not need an external voltage for the scaling, resistors would suffice for that.

Comment: @MichaelGorsich You said "*It is simply **impossible**, with just resistors, to put 0.0 volts in and get 0.5 volts (i.e., the offset) out*". - Not impossible at all.

Comment: @Harry Of course it's impossible.  Are you skipping the "with just resistors" part?  Your solution, which is fine by the way, is not just resistors, it includes a very, VERY necessary additional component: the external voltage source.  You are NOT putting 0 volts in, adding resistors, and getting 0.5 volts out.  That's all I was originally saying in my comment to Jasen's original comment, which suggested the OPs requirements could be met with a resistor network.

Comment: @Harry And after having said that, I just thought of a way your circuit (with the 400 Hz) could work with no +5 external:  You could add a diode pump at the input to charge up a cap, a Zener to regulate the pump output, and use that offset. <<sigh>> have a good day!

Comment: @MichaelGorsich Ah, I see now that I misunderstood you. All is fine, m8.

Comment: @MichaelGorsich, I wasn't counting ground, or a voltage source as a part, most devices already have these things.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[Link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%203.5993318835628396%2050%205%2050%0Ar%20288%2096%20288%20160%200%201000%0Ar%20288%20160%20288%20224%200%201000%0Ag%20288%20224%20288%20240%200%0AR%20288%2096%20288%2064%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20224%20160%20288%20160%200%20125%0Aw%20352%20160%20384%20160%202%0Aw%20352%20368%20384%20368%202%0Ar%20224%20368%20288%20368%200%202000%0AR%20288%20304%20288%20272%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20288%20432%20288%20448%200%0Ar%20288%20368%20288%20432%200%201000%0Ar%20288%20304%20288%20368%200%206000%0Aw%20224%20368%20224%20160%202%0AR%20224%20160%20192%20160%200%203%20400%202.5%202.5%200%200.5%0Aw%20352%20160%20288%20160%200%0Aw%20352%20368%20288%20368%200%0Ao%2013%208%200%204354%205%200.00625%200%202%2013%203%0Ao%205%208%200%204354%205%200.00009765625%201%202%205%203%0Ao%206%208%200%204354%205%200.00009765625%202%202%206%203%0A) to simulation.

- Left graph = The triangle wave source that goes from 0 V to 5 V
- Middle graph = upper Y network's output
- Right graph = bottom Y network's output

With two Y networks you can solve your scaling issues.

The formula for calculating the node at the middle of the Y network is the following equation:

\$V_{middle}=\dfrac{V_aR_bR_c+V_bR_aR_c+V_cR_aR_b}{R_aR_b+R_bR_c+R_aR_b}\$

As you can see, it is linear, it's namely an averaging function, like \$\frac{V_a+V_b+V_c}{3}\$ but with weights.

---

You can solve this mathematically, and plug equations into each other and end up with some value for the resistors. Or you can just enter your favorite simulator, mine is CircuitJS. Set the input to the maximum of the limits and change the resistors until you get your wanted output value. And then set your input to the minimum value and change the resistors again, go back to top value and repeat.

I had calculated the 125 Ω from the equation above by turning \$R_c\$ into \$R_b\$ because 0.5 and 4.5 is balanced (as you can see by the two 1 kΩ resistors).

The bottom Y network that gives 0.5 V and 2 V was made by simply changing the resistors in the simulator until I saw the output that you sought.

---

If you are going to attach a load to the output of these Y networks, then you will definitely want to [buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Voltage_follower_(unity_buffer_amplifier)) the output. A load in this sense would be some resistor between the output of the Y network and ground that is less than... say 10 kΩ. Above 10 kΩ you will still distort the signal.

If your input has high impedance, meaning that it will have issues with giving the current into the Y network, then you might want to buffer the input.

---

### Edit

Op is right, brute-forcing your way to a solution is against the engineer code.

So here's the proper mathematical expression for \$R_b\$ and \$R_c\$:

\$
\scriptsize{
\begin{array}{l l}
V_a^+ & \text{= Maximum input voltage}\\
V_o^+ & \text{= Output at that voltage}\\
V_a^- & \text{= Minimum input voltage}\\
V_o^- & \text{= Output at that voltage}\\
V_b   & \text{= Positive rail voltage}\\
V_c   & \text{= Negative rail voltage}\\
R_a   & \text{= Resistor from output to input}\\
R_b   & \text{= Resistor from output to positive rail}\\
R_c   & \text{= Resistor from output to negative rail}\\
\end{array}
}
\$

\$
R_b = \dfrac{V_b-V_o^+}{\frac{V_a^+-V_o^+}{R_a}+\frac{V_c-V_o^+}{R_c}}\\
R_c = Ra\dfrac{(V_b-V_o^+)(V_c-V_o^-)-(V_c-V_o^+)(V_b-V_o^-)}{(V_b-V_o^-)(V_a^+-V_o^+)-(V_b-V_o^+)(V_a^--V_o^-)}
\$

So the idea here is that you choose \$R_a\$, then solve for \$R_c\$ and use that value to get \$R_b\$.

Or you just use this equation for \$R_b\$:

\$
R_b = -R_a\dfrac{(V_b-V_o^+)(V_c-V_o^-)-(V_c-V_o^+)(V_b-V_o^-)}{(V_c-V_o^-)(V_a^+-V_o^+)-(V_c-V_o^+)(V_a^--V_o^-)}
\$

### Example 1:

\$
\scriptsize{
\begin{array}{l l l}
V_a^+ & 5\text{ V} &\text{= Maximum input voltage}\\
V_o^+ & 4.5\text{ V} &\text{= Output at that voltage}\\
V_a^- & 0\text{ V} &\text{= Minimum input voltage}\\
V_o^- & 0.5\text{ V} &\text{= Output at that voltage}\\
V_b   & 5\text{ V} &\text{= Positive rail voltage}\\
V_c   & 0\text{ V} &\text{= Negative rail voltage}\\
R_a   & 125\text{ Ω} &\text{= Resistor from output to input}\\
R_b   & ?\text{ Ω} &\text{= Resistor from output to positive rail}\\
R_c   & ?\text{ Ω} &\text{= Resistor from output to negative rail}\\
\end{array}
}
\$

$$
\begin{align}
R_c &= Ra\dfrac{(V_b-V_o^+)(V_c-V_o^-)-(V_c-V_o^+)(V_b-V_o^-)}{(V_b-V_o^-)(V_a^+-V_o^+)-(V_b-V_o^+)(V_a^--V_o^-)}\\
\\
&= 125\dfrac{(5-4.5)(0-0.5)-(0-4.5)(5-0.5)}{(5-0.5)(5-4.5)-(5-4.5)(0-0.5)}\\
\\
&= 1000Ω
\end{align}
$$

And we don't need to calculate \$R_b\$ because we know it is also 1 kΩ in this case, so let's calculate \$R_b\$ in another example.

### Example 2:

\$
\scriptsize{
\begin{array}{l l l}
V_a^+ & 5\text{ V} &\text{= Maximum input voltage}\\
V_o^+ & 2\text{ V} &\text{= Output at that voltage}\\
V_a^- & 0\text{ V} &\text{= Minimum input voltage}\\
V_o^- & 0.5\text{ V} &\text{= Output at that voltage}\\
V_b   & 5\text{ V} &\text{= Positive rail voltage}\\
V_c   & 0\text{ V} &\text{= Negative rail voltage}\\
R_a   & 2000\text{ Ω} &\text{= Resistor from output to input}\\
R_b   & ?\text{ Ω} &\text{= Resistor from output to positive rail}\\
R_c   & ?\text{ Ω} &\text{= Resistor from output to negative rail}\\
\end{array}
}
\$

$$
\begin{align}
R_b &= -R_a\dfrac{(V_b-V_o^+)(V_c-V_o^-)-(V_c-V_o^+)(V_b-V_o^-)}{(V_c-V_o^-)(V_a^+-V_o^+)-(V_c-V_o^+)(V_a^--V_o^-)}\\
\\
&= -2000\dfrac{(5-2)(0-0.5)-(0-2)(5-0.5)}{(0-0.5)(5-2)-(0-2)(0-0.5)}\\
\\
&= 6000Ω
\end{align}
$$

And if you would've used the previous expression for \$R_c\$, then you would've gotten 1 kΩ.

So both of my equations agree with my schematic at the top of this answer.

### Tada!

Comment: wow cool, the 'brute-force' method for the bottom Y network is interesting -- I hadn't thought to try that. Thanks !

Comment: @user248244 Well it was honestly quicker. I could either set up the mathematical expressions => 15 minutes of intense thinking. Or just go to a simulator and fiddle with the resistors for 30 seconds. - Though if I want some other output then I need to fiddle 30 seconds again, unlike with a formula I would have the answer in 2 seconds. - FYI, the ratios are the important thing. You will get the same resolution if you multiply all resistances by a factor 10, or reduce by a factor 10. I chose these medium-sized resistors because I like 1 kΩ.

Comment: @user248244 Now there's no brute-force.

Comment: Very nice solution.  Probably the simplest that works, and only needs an external voltage source (i.e., no active components) along with the resistors.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the first one. You can do the second one.

```
Input    Output
0 V      0.5 V
5 V      4.5 V
```

Note that the inputs and outputs are centred around 2.5 V with a reduction of 1/5.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyu6tu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Span adjustment and (b) the offset addition.*

You need to create a 2.5 V reference somehow. This can be done with a suitable Zener, an op-amp buffered voltage divider, etc.

Comment: Hint: 4 kohms to 2.5 V is equivalent to 8 kohms to 5 V and 8 kohms to 0 V.

Comment: That's a lot simpler than I had imagined -- thank you. Are diodes required on either side of the resistors, post resistor?

Comment: Diodes are generally only required for over/under-voltage protection. There's no requirement for that in your question as the input voltage is 0 to 5 V.